# How would you display an object which is inside another object from an API call in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

The object I'm trying to display is from the ISS Tracker API:

```js
{
  "message": "success", 
  "timestamp": UNIX_TIME_STAMP, 
  "iss_position": {
    "latitude": CURRENT_LATITUDE, 
    "longitude": CURRENT_LONGITUDE
  }
}
```

I called the API using this code:

```
 componentDidMount(){
    fetch("http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        this.setState({
            position: data
        })
    })
}
```

The data I currently want to display is the latitude. I can display the timestamp and message using

```
render(){
    return(
        <div>
           {this.state.position.timestamp}
        </div>
    )
}
```

However I can't seem to display the latitude when I do

```
render(){
    return(
        <div>
           {this.state.position.iss_position.latitude}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting? What is the output?

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'latitude')

Comment: Can you try to console `this.state.position.iss_position`?

Comment: How have you initialised your state? The error probably comes from the initial render when there is no `iss_position` property

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try using optional chaining `this.state.position?.iss_position?.latitude`.